# Plotting 2 dynamically-sized series on ONE line with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, array, concatenation

My problem is: with excel, I want to plot 2 series on one line, where the first series has a changing size.
Here is an example to better understand it:

- List_1: can be `[0,1,2,3,4,0]` or `[0,1,2,...,15,16,0]`
- List_2: is always the same, eg: `[0,1,2,3,0]`
- Time  : I have a time column to use as an x-axis, eg: `[0,0.1,0.2,...,2.50]`

What I am looking for is a way to graph List_1 and List_2 on one continuous line in a graph.

I experimented with naming List_1 using the Name Manager in Excel, but I can't seem to make out of 2 lists only one. I also tried the `CONCATENATE()` function in Excel to no success, in fact, what I need is an array, not an un-separated string of numbers.

Comment: Not sure what you want. List_1 and List_2 are Y values, and List_1 can contain either of two sets of values? Are these values in the worksheet?